# HTACCESS creating permalinks

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks

I want to rewrite "http://domain.com/url-name/",
to look at "http://domain.com/?url="url-name".

I am trying this but with no success :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$/  ^([^/]*)?url=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes:

- In regex, if you escape `$` then it will match literal `$`.
- In the target URI, you cannot use regex but provide back-reference to captured value in the pattern.
- Use `RewriteCond` to affect only non-files and non-directories.

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* ?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: :( no its not working , what could be the problem ? (i didn't mention that i am doing this on a localhost not on a real host)

Comment: i am sorry my friend , you are right, i will give you all the details. I am using xampp, so i created the .htaccess file with the conditions you gave me. Than i entered on the browser this url :
http://localhost/?url=post-name . No error was given. Simply nothing happened. The .htaccess file is in the root directory same as index.php.

Comment: Exactly :D i though i had to write it and than it would look like that , anyway thank you very much, it works as a charm :D .

Comment: Hello again my friend , how can we make this possible for more url get variables , expamle this url : example.com/category-name/post-name/ , example.com/?category=cat&&post=catalyst

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ ?category=$1&&post=$2 [L,QSA]` with same 2 `RewriteCond` as above

Comment: Hello again my friend. I was hoping if there could be a modification to the first rule you gave me , make something like ignore the first get variable , example :  example.com/en/about-us/ , but en is going to be a folder so how ? :/

Comment: @LuarbBalla: Please post a new question referencing this one so that I can help you better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216671/ignore-first-variable-on-link-using-htaccess-permalinks