# Ignore first variable on link using HTACCESS permalinks

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using this htaccess rules to create permalinks on the root folder of a domain :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* ?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Now i want to use the same rules but on a folder inside this website because
i want to make it in two different languages.
So if i create a folder: example.com/en/  , i want this conditions to apply
same as in the root folder for calling links as below but ignoring the first get variable:

example.com/about-us/ || example.com/en/about-us/

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess with an additional rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.*)$ ?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule .* ?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: should i apply this on both levels or just one of them ? because i am getting the same result like  /en/  is not a folder but a a variable,  but if  i empty it , it worked also with the first rule i posted .

Comment: If you had just one rule in your .htaccess as shown in question then replace all of your .htaccess with the code in my answer